# facebook login error: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-login, omniauth

I have created a facebook app and had filled in all my credentials correctly, am using Omniauth for adding facebook login in my rails app.

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

**my secrets.yml**

```
### NOT MY REAL KEYS
development:
  secret_key_base: mykeybase
  facebook_api_id: 12345678910110
  facebook_api_secret: d3c47c5858fb953ae3ec11df46cekjhg
  twitter_api_id: <%= ENV["TWITTER_API_ID"] %>
  twitter_api_secret: <%= ENV["TWITTER_API_SECRET"] %>
  google_api_id: <%= ENV["123456789101-lmpsdsdd74bts698uc8pu32d8tqjhis.apps.googleusercontent.com"] %>
  google_api_secret: <%= ENV["tnJ1lJJESADhgdfDEhg-D-6D"] %>

test:
  secret_key_base: e4dfde8a4ac1f9b257af3e709c8a6544f6896bbbd8f0804f120c47a836220236e0ea158b793de6e67c6e0c2be2d197c5f367e9160648d85547286199856d5f05



production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  facebook_api_id: <%= ENV["12345678910110"] %>
  facebook_api_secret: <%= ENV["d3c47c5858fb953ae3ec11df46ce1fe3"] %>
  twitter_api_id: <%= ENV["TWITTER_API_ID"] %>
  twitter_api_secret: <%= ENV["TWITTER_API_SECRET"] %>
  google_api_id: <%= ENV["23456789101-lmpsdsdd74bts698uc8pu32d8tqjhis.apps.googleusercontent.com"] %>
  google_api_secret: <%= ENV["tnJ1lJJESADhgdfDEhg-D-6D"] %>
```

**my facebook sdk**

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '12345678910110',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.9'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**my routes**

```
  devise_for :admins, controllers: { sessions: 'admin/sessions' }
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**FACEBOOK**
Valid OAuth redirect URIs: `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callbacks?close`

Site URL: `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Did you whitelist the redirect URI  in the app’s Client OAuth Settings?

Comment: That's what am not getting @jvillian how to do that

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#surfacearea

Comment: does i have to add the redirect URI in my code...coz i have already added it in my facebook app @CBroe

Comment: You have to add what redirect URL your code actually produces, into your Facebook app settings ... check the URL of the login dialog when you get the error message shown - the value the redirect_uri parameter has there must be in your app settings. (Minus the URL-encoding, obviously.)

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you should register `http://localhost:3000` as a valid url with http://developers.facebook.com against your app.

Comment: am new to this...where should i add the url

Comment: This might help https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/97715   There should be some connect on fb dev site also on how to do it.

Comment: Agarwal...no buddy am still struggling with it...i tried with some different URLS to redirect and that worked but it doesn't make the user signup or signin it takes the user back to the login page...